# .htaccess que acepte ñ

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo un hack para virtuemart que a traves de un codigo php:

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path));
$w = imagesx($image);$h = imagesy($image);


$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('watermark.png');
$ww = imagesx($watermark);
$wh = imagesy($watermark);

imagecopy($image, $watermark, (($w/1)-($ww/1)), (($h-40)-($wh/1.35)), 0, 0, $ww, $wh);

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');
imagejpeg($image,null,95);
exit();?>
```

sobreescribe las imagenes de un directorio con este .htaccess para incluir el watermark.png en las imagenes:

```
RewriteRule ^(resized)($|/) - [L]

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f

RewriteRule \.(gif|jpeg|jpg|png)$ watermark.php [QSA,NC]
```

El problema es que hay archivos con ñ que parece ser que no identifica el codigo y en consecuencia, hace que no funcione.

Alguien puede ayudarme para saber que habria que poner para que reconozca los archivos que contengan ñ?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta. Por favor comenta si resuelve tu problema

Comment: Siento contestar con tanta demora. Pero efectivamente esa es la solucion para decodificar correctamente la ñ. 
Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema no es con las reglas del `.htaccess` ni con lo que se identifica en el código.

Cuando se obtiene la URL con `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` en:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

se encuentra codificada. Por ejemplo, la URL `/felizaño.png` es recibida cómo `/feliza%C3%B1o.png`.

Para decodificar una URL, se usa la función [rawurldecode()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.rawurldecode.php).

```
$path = rawurldecode($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```